# Adjusting position of the page number

Tags: pagestyle

How can I put the page number to the bottom and very middle of the page? I now have:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, german]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm,}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{array}
\pagestyle{headings}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\pagestyle{plain}` instead of `\pagestyle{headings}`. This will center the page number at the foot of the page but will not print any headings at the top of the page. If you want both headings and a centered page number use the `fancyhdr` package (`> texdoc fancyhdr` for the manual).

Comment: I tried it with fancyhdr but it doesnt really work for me.. it puts the new headline above my last headline and sometimes there is no headline with fancyhdr..

Comment: You also may try with `titleps`, from the `titlesec` bundle. It is  simpler to use than `fancyhdr`, in my opinion.

Comment: I tried both, but i does not really work for me. Can someone post the commands for headline in fancy and page  number at the bottom?

Comment: Add to your preamble : `\usepackage{fancyhdr,floatpag}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear page header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\floatpagestyle{fancy}% Page style for float-page only`

Comment: If i put all that in i dont have a header at all..